# Stock file that takes orders and produces a list or products bought

Tags: python

Here is my code for a database and I have used a text file and inserted it into the code, however when it reaches line 27 it comes up with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\computing\databse\task 2.py", line 27, in <module>
    print("you bought", + products[i][1], "at a cost of", +str(products_total))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

I have tried looking at lots of different websites however I cannot figure out how to fix it or what is wrong with the code and why it will not work! Everything else appears to be working fine, if someone could help me out a tiny bit I would be extremely grateful:

```
products = []
with open('StockFile.txt','r') as i:
    for line in i:
        line = line[:-1]
        row = line.split(',')
        products.append(row)

    print(products)

total = 0
items = []
answer = "yes"
while answer == "yes":
    GTIN = input ("Please input GTIN:")
    found = False
    for i in range (0,len(products)):
        if GTIN == products[i][0]:
            found = True
            items.append(GTIN)
            items.append(products[i][1])
            items.append(products[i][2])

            quantity = input("How many would you like?")
            items.append(quantity)
            product_total = int(quantity) * float (products[i][2])
            items.append(product_total)
            print("you bought", + products[i][1], "at a cost of",    +str(products_total))

            total = total + products_total

    if found == False:
        print("Sorry not a valid number try again")
    print("DO you want another item?")
    answer = input()
for i in range(0,len(items),5):
    print(items[i], items[i+1], items[i+2], items[i+3], items[i+4])
print("total cost of the order is £" +str(total))
```

Here is the text file I am using:

13245627,Nuts and bolts, 0.5
34512340,plain brackets, 1
56756777,100mm bolts, 2.5
90673412,L-shaped brackets, 0.7

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in the line of code:

```
print("you bought", + products[i][1], "at a cost of",    +str(products_total))
```

Try removing the `+`, so that it looks like:

```
print("you bought",  str(products[i][1]), "at a cost of", str(products_total))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing two methods of printing a series of objects: presenting each object as a separate argument by separating them with commas, and concatenating strings with the `+` operator. As a result, you ended up with a single argument `+str(products_total)`. The `str` class doesn't know what to do with that `+` sign before it.

Either stick with separating all your args with commas:

```
print("you bought", products[i][1], "at a cost of", products_total)
```

Or concatenate the strings (in which case you'll need to convert `products[i][1]` to a `str`, too):

```
print("you bought" + str(products[i][1]) + "at a cost of" + str(products_total))
```

Better yet, use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) and you won't need to do either:

```
print("you bought {0} at a cost of {1}".format(products[i][1], products_total))
```